# Observation: SE CSS was changed, now the humor in my profile was exposed

Tags: discussion, design

By accident I discovered that the following text could be embedded with a dark font on a dark background in [the user profile info page](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/396/makerofthings).

Following the spirit of IT Sec I pasted the following message:

```
---
A secret message goes here. Security through obscurity ...in action. 
---
```

Which was of course unreadable.  I'll assume this is by design, and you just cleaned up some CSS.

I will say it was fun while it lasted.

Comment: I like it - hadn't spotted that:-)

Comment: Related to http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/489/unreadable-quote-block-titles-in-the-user-profiles-on-security ?

Comment: Nice.  I was going to suggest you switch to using the spoiler markdown:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers  But, it seems that doesn't work on profile pages.

Comment: this is probably still possible with other HTML features, such as comments